# ansible sudo user not really sudo

Tags: sudo, ansible

I am trying to change source.list.

The host have a user `deploy` with password `deploy` which one I can connect ssh and make whatever with source.list using `sudo`. However ansible seems to not really do sudo with this user. Thats behavior happen with all task and roles that need sudo.

**inventory:**

```
machine ansible_ssh_host=172.23.0.43 ansible_connection=ssh ansible_ssh_user=deploy ansible_ssh_pass=deploy
```

**roles/apt-sources/tasks/main.yml**

```
- name: Copy source list
  copy: src=sources.list dest=/etc/apt/sources.list
```

**playbook.yml**

```
---
- name: apt and base system
  hosts: machine
  sudo_user: deploy
  sudo: True
  roles:
    - apt-sources
```

**ansible output**

```
failed: [machine] => {"failed": true, "md5sum": "74b6936296cdd0c94ef9b1f848bf2dab"}
msg: Destination /etc/apt not writable

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
           to retry, use: --limit @/home/montells/provision.retry

machine                : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

**using**

- ansible: v1.6.6
- Host OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Try remove `sudo_user` and see if that helps.

Comment: when remove `sudo_user` then ansible hangs out

Comment: hangs as in never complete some specific task? Usually this is a sign that some software is waiting for user interaction (enter something from the keyboard) and the ansible task is borked.

Comment: I enter `yes` or `deploy` or `enter key it self` and nothing. only `Ctrl+C` and log **^CERROR: interrupted**

Comment: !!!Surprisingly. If I create a password for user `root` and enable ssh  for `root`, and sustitute `deploy` user for `root` user in ansible inventory  and playbook. It works. Thats is wierd for me, because `deploy` user is sudoers too

Comment: @montells you don't want to sudo *to* `deploy`, you want to log in as deploy and sudo to root from there. That's why people are (correctly) telling you to remove sudo_user.

Comment: @tedder42 I want log as deploy and sudo as deploy too. Is it possible?

Comment: @montells you want to log in as deploy and sudo *to* root from deploy. sudo_user is for "sudoing *to* deploy *from* deploy", which doesn't make much sense. The only time you specify sudo_user is if your system doesn't use 'root' as the root account.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not confuse **sudo_user** and **remote_user**

**sudo_user** - is privileged user you're switching to perform some command not allowed for regular user (default value, obviously - root)

**remote_user** - used to build SSH connection

You have already specified remote_user on your inventory, so just remove/comment sudo_user line and retry your playbook run

Comment: @mikko-ohtamaa recommended me that, but when remove sudo_user then ansible hangs out

Comment: @ghloogh's answer is correct about "don't use sudo_user". there's something wrong with your role. Please post the apt-sources task source or (better) create a new question about that.

Comment: now that the 'apt-sources' task is posted, it's clear. sudo_user should not be there. /etc/apt/* is owned by root, so by ssh'ing in as 'deploy', then sudoing to the 'deploy' user, you can't write that file.

Comment: @montells are your 'deploy' user allowed to run commands without entering sudo password (NOPASSWD)? If not, try to run your playbook with `--ask-sudo-pass` parameter